# I am trying to create a Download Button but file is not downloading?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, dom, download

I am creating download button having click listener which request server to download file

code click listener:

```
 downloadFileClick(event){
   $.ajax('/download', {data:{}}).done(function(data){

   }.bind(this));
 }
```

at server side following code is running

```
app.get('/download', function(req, res){
  var file = __dirname + '/write/imageout.png';
  res.download(file);
});
```

file is not downloading in browser. I checked response send from server to client it sending file content but it not downloading from browser.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download a file by jQuery.Ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545311/download-a-file-by-jquery-ajax)

Comment: Try replacing your `res.download(file);` with `window.open(file);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not download a file by making an ajax request to that file. The Browser will ignore this. You have to open the file via `<a href="/download" download>` or you can trigger that from jQuery:

```
var a = $("<a>");
a.attr("href", "/download");
a.attr("download", "img.png");  // this is important
a.appendTo("body");
a[0].click();
a.remove();
```

This should download the browser image correctly.